# How to replace a ',' in a column with a string (ex '-58,00') with a '.' in python (like find&replace in excel)?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, replace

I'm trying to get more insights of my bank data. I want to look at the total sum per category, but I can't seem to make a float of the amounts in the dataset.

I've uploaded the data (csv-file) into a dataframe (bank), that looks something like this:

```
 date        amount   category
 2018-09-01  -58,00   dinner 
 2018-09-02  -60,00   grocery
 2018-09-02  -115,00  clothing
```

I've tried to use .replace and .astype(float), both didn't work

```py
#I've tried this formula, but it doesn't work (the x-values even get shuffled??): 

#replace ',' with '.' in amount:
def komma(x):
    for x in bank['amount']:
        x = list(set(x))
        for a in x:
            if a == ',':
                a.replace(",",".")
    return "".join(x)

komma(x)
bank.head()

#my result with .replace(',','.') is no changes in the dataframe 
#my result with .astype(float) was 
#ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-58,00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
df["amount"]=df["amount"].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)
```

(no need of any for loop there)

Comment: Thank you soooo much Grzegorz, you really helped me!

Comment: No worries, please upvote, and mark as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
df["amount"]=df["amount"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))
```

however, converting to float after converting ',' to '.' might lead to data precision loss.

```
         date  amount  category
0  2018-09-01   -58.0    dinner
1  2018-09-02   -60.0   grocery
2  2018-09-02  -115.0  clothing
```

Comment: Thank you Dexter0411, but why might it lead to data precision loss?

Comment: Hi, i observed that after the character exchange and converting the column to float, if there are only leading 0's after a decimal point, python formats it to single 0 after decimal. Ex 99.000 will be formatted to 99.0 by default

Comment: Thank you Dexter0411 for this clear explanation. This is not the case with the solution from Grzegorz, so I will use that one.